# Change Letter inside a test file

Tags: powershell

I have a file that has character that deems it production or test.

P=production
T=test

```
select-string "\\myfileserver\files\999.80214.va.000000373.20210122.173314.20210755" -pattern "T"
```

The above returns a True. I need to change that T to a P in the file

```
999.80214.va.000000373.20210122.173314.20210755:1:ISA*00* 00 ZZ*83-1002042 *ZZ*841469824 *210 123*0753*$*00501*000000209*0*T:
```

How do I search for the T in this string

Comment: [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.1) and regex might be your friends in this case. Please read the help including the examples to learn how to use them.

Comment: I've tried select string with no luck so far.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what might work?'

Answer (score 0):

OK, with all the necessary infomration we gathered step by step I'd come up with this simple solution:

```
$Path = '\\myfileserver\files\999.80214.va.000000373.20210122.173314.20210755'
$Content = Get-Content -Path $Path
$NewContent = 
(($Content | Select-Object -First 1) -replace '(?<=\*)T(?=:$)','P'),
($Content | Select-Object -Skip 1)
Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $NewContent
```

It takes the content of the file, changes only the first line, combines this new first line with the original unchanged rest of the file and writes it back to the original file.

Comment: Thanks but this one so far returns blank results.

Comment: So your input file looks diffenrent to what I thought after reading your question. Why don't you show a few (sanitized) lines of the original file (formatted as code please) in your question?

Comment: 999.80214.va.000000373.20210122.173314.20210755:1:ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*83-1002042     *ZZ*841469824      *210
123*0753*$*00501*000000209*0*T*:

Comment: I was able to figure out the query but that doesnt change the Value I need to change in the file.

Comment: I saw that you changed your question. I cannot help you if I dont have enough information. I added one very simple solution to my answer.

Comment: Your above comment "-ireplace 'T','P'" Can you should be what the full command looks like.

Comment: It is the full command. You do not share enough information about the file. I cannot see your screen and I cannot read your mind. Please update your question with all information about the file.

Comment: Its a txt file that I need to search the first line in that file and change the T=test to a P=production. I'm not really sure how else I can explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Again - that should be in your question! ;-)  ... and it helps to know that the file has more than just this one line but you are only interested in this first line ... thanks. ... will think about and change the code ... give me some moments....

Comment: OK ... try it now.